# strcpy assertion error c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assertions, strcpy

I am a student Just learning c++ so I am sure there are much more efficient ways of doing this; with that said I would really appreciate some help figuring out why my program crashes. I have narrowed it down the a strcpy function that crashes everything and breaks it, which I have commented out and labeled. I have obviously used the strcpy function multiple times in the program with similar parameters, so I don't understand why that specific one crashes. I have tried everything I can think of and really appreciate the help. As of now I have a lot commented out so it should run with the right text file named "bookdb" my text file currently has this in it

```
Active Learning Approach,Randal Albert,9780763757236,1,650,1,<br>
Technical Communications,John Lannon,9780321899972,2,724,0,
```

to see the error you will have to un-comment strcpy(bookArray[num_books].author_name, temp_authorName);

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>

enum Genres {HORROR=1, SCIFI, COMEDY, DRAMA, ACTION};


struct Book
{
    char title[100];
    char author_name[50];
    char isbn[14];
    Genres genre;
    int num_pages;
    bool paperback;
};

//Function Declarations
unsigned short ReadBooks(Book * bookArray, unsigned short & num_books);
void DisplayBooks(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books);
void ResizeArrays(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books);

int main ()
{
    unsigned short num_books = 0;
    Book * bookArray = new Book();

    num_books = ReadBooks(bookArray, num_books);

}//End Main

unsigned short ReadBooks(Book * bookArray, unsigned short & num_books)
{
    ifstream readBooks("bookdb.txt");
    char temp_title[100] = "0";
    char temp_authorName[100] = "0";
    char temp_isbn[14] = "0";

    char temp_genre[50] = "0";
    char temp_numPages[50] = "0";
    char temp_paperback[50] = "0";

    int genreNumber = 0,
        numPages = 0,
        paperback = 0;

    if (readBooks.is_open() )
    {
        cout << "The file was successfully opened\n" << endl;

        readBooks.getline(temp_title, 100, ',');//Reads into temp cstring
        strcpy(bookArray[num_books].title, temp_title); //copies to dynamic cstring
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].title << endl; //displays part of structure to make sure it worked!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_authorName, 100, ',');
        strcpy(bookArray[num_books].author_name, temp_authorName); 
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].author_name << endl; 

        readBooks.getline(temp_isbn, 14, ',');
        strcpy(bookArray[num_books].isbn, temp_isbn); 
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].isbn << endl;

        readBooks.getline(temp_genre, 50, ',');//Get the genre as a char
        genreNumber = atoi(temp_genre);//converts char to an int
        bookArray[num_books].genre = static_cast <Genres> (genreNumber);//converts int to ENUM
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].genre << endl;//Displays ENUM to make sure it worked!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_numPages, 50, ',');
        numPages = atoi(temp_numPages); //converts char to an int
        bookArray[num_books].num_pages = numPages; //assigns int to structure
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].num_pages << endl; //Displays part of structure to make sure to works!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_paperback, 50, ',');
        paperback = atoi(temp_paperback); //converts char to an int
        bookArray[num_books].paperback = static_cast <bool> (paperback);
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].paperback << endl;
        num_books++;

        //DisplayBooks(bookArray, num_books);
        ResizeArrays(bookArray, num_books);
        cout << "The number of books is: " << num_books << endl;

        //while (!readBooks.eof() )
        //{

        readBooks.getline(temp_title, 100, ',');//Reads into temp cstring
        strcpy(bookArray[num_books].title, temp_title); //copies to dynamic cstring
        cout << bookArray[num_books].title << endl; //displays part of structure to make sure it worked!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_authorName, 100, ',');
        cout << temp_authorName << endl; 
        //strcpy(bookArray[num_books].author_name, "0");
        ///THIS BREAKS MY CODE////strcpy(bookArray[num_books].author_name, temp_authorName); 
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].author_name << endl; 

        readBooks.getline(temp_isbn, 14, ',');
        //strcpy(bookArray[num_books].isbn, temp_isbn); 
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].isbn << endl;

        readBooks.getline(temp_genre, 50, ',');//Get the genre as a char
        //genreNumber = atoi(temp_genre);//converts char to an int
        //bookArray[num_books].genre = static_cast <Genres> (genreNumber);//converts int to ENUM
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].genre << endl;//Displays ENUM to make sure it worked!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_numPages, 1000, ',');
        //numPages = atoi(temp_numPages); //converts char to an int
        //bookArray[num_books].num_pages = numPages; //assigns int to structure
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].num_pages << endl; //Displays part of structure to make sure to works!!

        readBooks.getline(temp_paperback, 50, ',');
        //paperback = atoi(temp_paperback); //converts char to an int
        //bookArray[num_books].paperback = static_cast <bool> (paperback);
        //cout << bookArray[num_books].paperback << endl;*/

        num_books++;

        //ResizeArrays(bookArray, num_books);
        //}//End while

        readBooks.close();
    }//End if
    else
    {
        cout << "There was not an existing book file, so one will be created"  << endl;
    }//End else

    return 0;
}//End ReadBooks

void DisplayBooks(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books)
{
    for (unsigned short i = 0; i < num_books; i++)
    {
        cout << setw(30) << left << bookArray[i].title << left << setw(20) << bookArray[i].author_name << left << setw(15) << bookArray[i].isbn
             << left << setw(3) << bookArray[i].genre  << left<< setw(6) << bookArray[i].num_pages << left << setw(4) << bookArray[i].paperback << endl;
    }//End For
}//ENd Display Function

void ResizeArrays(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books)
{
    Book * temp_bookArray = new Book[num_books + 1];


    for (int i = 0; i < num_books; i++)
    {
        strcpy(temp_bookArray[i].title, bookArray[i].title);
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].title << endl; //For Debugging

        strcpy(temp_bookArray[i].author_name, bookArray[i].author_name);
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].author_name << endl; //for Debugging

        strcpy(temp_bookArray[i].isbn, bookArray[i].isbn);
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].isbn << endl;//for debugging

        temp_bookArray[i].genre = bookArray[i].genre;
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].genre << endl;//for debugging

        temp_bookArray[i].num_pages = bookArray[i].num_pages;
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].num_pages << endl;// for debugging

        temp_bookArray[i].paperback = bookArray[i].paperback; 
        //cout << temp_bookArray[i].paperback << endl; //for debugging


    }//End for

    delete [] bookArray;

    bookArray = temp_bookArray; 

    DisplayBooks(bookArray, num_books); //debugging to make sure bookArray is reassigned


}//End Resize Function
```

Comment: The problem that stands out is that you allocate a single `Book`, then you use a pointer to it as it it were an array. Drop the `new` and the pointers and it will be harder to make that kind of mistake.

Comment: The things you should get rid off when making the step from C to C++: `char []` in favor of `string`. *Any* kind of array in favor of `vector`. Pointer parameters in favor of references. Dynamic memory allocation outside of constructors. That's oversimplifying of course, but a good first rule of thumb. Your `struct Book` should be a class, the functions (`ReadBooks()`, `DisplayBooks()` etc.) members of that class. That's the bare minimum. You can ignore all the rest - inheritance, templates, exceptions etc. - but not doing the stuff I mentioned above, you can basically just stay with C. ;-)

Comment: There is too much broken in your code, which begs the question, how was it written? In any case, you should try to narrow the problem down to a single issue, and post minimal but self-contained code with which that issue can be reproduced. A wall of buggy code is too much for one question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are problems with the ResizeArrays:

- It allocates new memory for the array, but doesn't return that new array back to the calling function, so that it can adjust its pointers to the new array location.
- Resize probably needs to sizes, the old size, and the new size, and you will only be able to copy the minimum of those numbers of elements.

Just to fix this to the point where it will work, you can do something like:

```
Book* ResizeArrays(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books)
{ 
    ....
    return bookArray;
}
```

Then use the function in this way

```
bookArray = ResizeArrays(bookArray, num_books);
```

However, as you use an array delete, for your first allocate, you need to use an array allocation in main() as well,

```
Book * bookArray = new Book[1];
```

Even though its only allocating one book, it should be done as an array, so it is compatible with the delete [] used in ResizeArrays.

I assume this is a learning exercise.  In normal use of C++ you wouldn't use naked new and delete operators.  Either you would simply use std::vector or similar, or to create an object that will manage the memory, with the new and delete in the constructor and destructor respectively.

Comment: This may be true, but it is only one of many problems, and not the first one. Things get broken way before the call to `ResizeArrays`.

Comment: Yes, it does have problems, but fixing this seems to solve the memory allocation problems, and should be fairly easy to debug the rest from there.

Comment: I am pretty sure you just saved my whole project. Thank you so much!!! I see what went wrong there now. And to everyone else, I understand there are probably a million things wrong, but I am a college student just learning the language, with a teacher who doesn't have much experience with c++ either. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

strlen gets all elements without '\0',so if you have str = "1234";
the str length is 5,(1234 + '\0) but return 4.Strcpy take all 5 elements + '\0' .

Answer (score -1):

Problems that I see:

**Problem 1**

There isn't enough space to hold the ISBN properly. The length of ISBN in your input file is 14 characters long. To hold them in a null terminated string, you need to have an array that can hold 15 or more characters.

As a result, the line

```
    readBooks.getline(temp_isbn, 14, ',');
```

will stop reading after 13 characters since it has to use the 14-th character to store `'\0'`.

**Problem 2**

This line doesn't look right.

```
    readBooks.getline(temp_numPages, 1000, ',');
```

I suspect this was a typo and you meant

```
    readBooks.getline(temp_numPages, 50, ',');
```

**Problem 3**

There are problems with handling of memory in `ResizeArray`.

```
void ResizeArrays(Book * bookArray, unsigned short num_books)
{
    Book * temp_bookArray = new Book[num_books + 1];

    // Here, you are deleting the memory that was allocated in `main`.
    // bookArray in the calling function now points to memory that has been
    // deleted here.
    delete [] bookArray;

    // Here, you are changing the value of bookArray but only
    // locally in this function. This assignment doesn't
    // change the value of bookArray in the calling function.
    bookArray = temp_bookArray; 

    DisplayBooks(bookArray, num_books); //debugging to make sure bookArray is reassigned


}//End Resize Function
```

If you change `ResizeArray` to:

```
void ResizeArrays(Book*& bookArray, unsigned short num_books)
```

things will be better.

**Problem 4**

I see that you have commented out the `while` loop in `ReadBooks`. If you decide to bring that loop back to life, you'll have to resize `bookArray` in each run of the loop.

**Suggestion**
It will be easier to use an `std::vector<Book*>` to hold the books instead of allocating memory for arrays of `Books`.

Comment: No, everything should not be OK.

Comment: Thank you for the help! When I do that the bookArray[i].title in the resize function gives an undefined error. I thought by doing this bookArray = temp_bookArray; i was reassigning the pointer to the new dynamic memory and my logic was if I pass a the bookArray pointer it is a memory address, meaning anything I change will change it in memory. Is this a flaw in my logic? Again thank you again for the help!

Comment: Sending a pointer allows you to change the memory pointed to by that pointer.  But here you are changing the location of that block of memory.  So actually you need to send a pointer to the pointer, so you can change the pointer.  You can achieve that by sending as a reference, or returning the new value, as in the other answer.